How does PhD funding work in STEM in Europe?
As a European student (and EU citizen) I have been considering a PhD for several years now and as I am contacting researchers in several European countries as potential advisors. A better understanding of how PhD projects are funded would be useful. 
My questions are:

How do researchers find funding for PhD projects?

If a motivated and qualified student has identified a suitable topic for a PhD project, can the student find the necessary funding alone? If not, how is funding arranged?


I am aware that these are wide-ranging questions that have probably as many answer as there are countries and research fields. I am interested specifically in funding for STEM PhDs that are unlikely to attract industry funding.

There is no uniform funding structure for PhDs in Europe. In many cases, there isn’t even a uniform funding structure in a single department of a single institution.

This question is similar to: How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Sursula I believe that the second point of my question (how could a motivated student mobilise the necessary funding alone?) differ from the question you rightfully pointed out. However, when reading the answers for the available European countries there are few, if any, mentions of cases where the student would be a grant holder presenting a project to a potential supervisor. This doesn't mean it's impossible but if it was a thing it would have been mentioned. I guess we can leave the question open until the end of the week in the case someone wants to add something and then close it?

@Patou A post should focus on one question to begin with. If you find yourself thinking "but it answers only one of my two questions" then remove the one already answered.

Europe is a big place with many countries and not all have the same traditions. But, in many places, doctoral students are employees; faculty members, though low level ones. One earns a salary. Their doctoral studies are a by-product of their employment. This is true in Germany, but I don't know that it is uniform even there. The student/employee will have a supervisor for purposes of the degree and that person or their group will be responsible for additional funding in some fields that require such things as experimental apparatus beyond what is generally available. This funding may come from grants to the supervisor.
As an employee, one will have access to the various seminars and working groups that bring faculty with common interests together.
There are likely other possible arrangements, but this is the one I'm most familiar with from contact with people in both UK and Germany. These folks are all in CS.
Generally speaking, admission is probably through the individual supervisor rather than a general admissions committee. For specifics on admissions in various places see the canonical question on doctoral admissions. Some of the answers there have specific information about funding.
It is probably useful to have ideas about a project, but that needs to be negotiated with the supervisor.

In the context of this question: where the PhD student is funded via an employment contract, one typically applies for such a position which is advertised already with a topic which one finds interesting. Alternatively, one may ask the supervisor of a group doing work in a general direction that one finds interesting, what particular positions are open now or in the near future, then applies for them. Then, within the scope of that project, there will hopefully be some freedom to develop one's own particular focuses.

"but I don't know that it is uniform even there" it is AFAIK the most typical form in STEM. But (e.g. as opposed to Italy, where AFAIK a PhD candidate has to be employed as such for 3 years) this is not a hard requirement. E.g. I basically handed in my PhD thesis at a university/faculty which had formally known me only for a very short time (days or weeks) and with which I never had any formal connection but the handing in, defense and subsequently receiving the PhD. The Prof knew me via work at a non-university research institution, though. The actual work had been done at another university.

It is rarely the case in the UK that PhD students are legally regarded as employed faculty members,  even if many departments test them as though they were.

Some two cents from someone who did their PhD in Germany: just because we are employed doesn’t mean that funding isn’t a concern. Where the money for an employee comes from is flexible and it was the norm that our supervisor tried to get us into funded programs or projects so that the "group funding" could be used for other people. I started on the group fund and ended up being paid by a graduate school and collaborating institute, for example. Special funding also often translates to a higher salary plus additional funding for travel and hardware.
